# Change custom actionbar title

Tags: android, android-actionbar, title

I'm using a custom layout to center the title of the actiobar.

```
  ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar(); 
  actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
  actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar);
```

where action_bar is a simple linear layout with a textview

My problem is that I need every activity to have different names - and I need to change theme programmatically. So I'm trying something like this:

```
private void setActiobarTitle(String title)
{
   LayoutInflater inflator  = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.action_bar, null);
   TextView titleTxtView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.actionbarTitle);
   titleTxtView.setText(title);
}
```

When debuging the textview is found and initialized and everything seems to be okay - but the title doesn't change.
Can anyone please tell me what seems to be the problem?

Comment: Where do you call this method?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Modify the setActionbarTitle() as below

```
 private void setActiobarTitle(String title)
 {

    View v = getActionbar().getCustomView();
    TextView titleTxtView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.actionbarTitle);
    titleTxtView.setText(title);
 }
```

Comment: I am getting Null pointer exception right on this line.TextView titleTxtView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.actionbarTitle); help?

Comment: @user2412816 do you have a view named actionbarTitle ??

Comment: @SathMK mine is tab_title and I have changed that.

Comment: enable custom view in actionbar usring 
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);