# Set the title of a custom ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I have a custom ActionBar layout, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="TITLE"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I apply the custom layout in my MainActivity like this:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar);
```

This actually shows a centered Text "TITLE", but still the old one too on the left. My app calls `getActionBar().setTitle(...)` a couple of times, and this results in the old title updating, the new title is left how it is.

Is it possible, e.g. by giving my title TextView a certain id, that `getActionBar().setTitle(...)` updates the TextView instead? Or do I have to implement a custom method for setting the title?

What do I have to do to make the old title disappear?

Does it have to do with using a NavigationDrawer and restoring the ActionBar? My restore method is like this:

```
private void restoreActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no Android Studio at hand but is it possible to override getActionBar() to return your own implementation?

Comment: And create my own ActionBar implementation that uses the custom title TextView? Yes I guess, but I doubt that this will make the old title disappear.

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20091791/change-custom-actionbar-title

Comment: @Terry well I'm just guessing :) but it seems like getActionBar() always returns the default bar, and overriding it would make it lose any reference to the default bar, making it disappear.

Comment: @milez you can design your own custom view to override the actionBar. That custom view will work as an actionBar then.

Comment: @Darkie How do I do that? Do you mean implementing my own ActionBar class and then somehow inject it so that it will be returned on `getActionBar()`?

Comment: @Terry look at the code I wrote below I am setting actionBar like regular but I took a view and assigned it to the actionBar so now my actionBar will be looking what I have done with the view.

Comment: @Terry sorry english is not my native language maybe I am not properly explaining to you.

Comment: @Terry - Darkie is right and you do not have to create a custom class. Can you try this getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

Answer (score 0):

This is how you set your custom actionBar:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#2B1C27")));

LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.titleview_2, null);

TextView actionbar_title = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.actionbar_title);
actionbar_title.setTypeface(youcanset your font here also.);

actionBar.setCustomView(v);
```

and in xml file try something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_gravity="center"
 android:id="@+id/actionBar"
 android:paddingTop="7dp"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:background="#9B66AB">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/actionbar_title"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
android:padding="8dp"
android:text="@string/appTitle"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView" />

<ImageView
android:layout_width="40dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/imageView"
android:background="@mipmap/logo"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/actionbar_title" />
```

Hope it helps... :)

Comment: If I set `actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);` the icon for the Navigation Drawer disappears. Or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: @Terry of course setting it equal to false will disappear the icon. because I am inflating the whole view inserting my own icon that's why I set it to false.

Comment: And `actionBar.setTitle()` will still set the old title, not the one in my custom layout.

Comment: @Terry yes that's why I set the custom view to actionBar not the setTitle().

Comment: you need to design your own custom view in order to completely disappear the properties of real actionBar. Custom view will cover it and work as a regular actionBar.

Comment: So you are saying that every time I want to change the title of the ActionBar, I first have to get the custom view, and then have to set the text of that, instead of calling `actionBar.setTitle()`. Right?

Comment: @Terry Oops yes that will be hard but this is how custom view works :)

Answer (score 0):

```
val actionb = supportActionBar
actionb!!.setTitle("My action bar")
actionb.subtitle = "Subtitle"
```